# Event handler throwing object reference error

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I am trying to create an event inside my class and handle it from static void main method.my event is triggered by a method named checkAge().But i have got an error like this :

> Error1-An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'Event.Program.m_AgeChecker(int)

I think i did all prats that i had to do,& i don't know what is the problem.

**Code of my first class**

```
class Mahmud
{    
    public Mahmud()
    {
        name = "mahmud";
        age = 25;
    }
    private string name;
    private int age;
    public string Name
    {
        get{return name;}
        set{name=value;}
    }
    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }
    public void checkAge()
    {           
     AgeUpdate(age);         
    }
    public delegate void AgeEventHandler(int mAge);
    public event AgeEventHandler AgeUpdate;        
}
```

**Code of the second class**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mahmud m = new Mahmud();
        m.AgeUpdate += new Event.Mahmud.AgeEventHandler(m_AgeChecker(m.Age));
        m.Age = 16;
        m.checkAge();
        m.Age = 27;
        m.checkAge();            
    }
    private void m_AgeChecker(int A)
    {
        if (A > 25)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ok");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `m_AgeChecker` needs to be static because it's called from a static method (`Main`).

Comment: @cubrr > would you mind adding some code here. thanks :)

Comment: You just make `m_AgeChecker` static...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are calling a non-static method from a static method.  You will need to make the method static.

```
static void m_AgeChecker(int A)
 {
    if (A > 25)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ok");
    }
}
```

Comment: i got new Error : method name expected

Comment: Pass only method name when creating:delegate new Event.Mahmud.AgeEventHandler(m_AgeChecker)